# get last element of array of unknown size

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I can get the first element of an array without knowing its length:

```
with foo as (
  select array_construct('duck','duck','goose') as a
)
select a[0] from foo -- returns 'duck'
```

But to get the last element I can't use the "pythonic" `a[-1]`, because `select a[-1] from foo` returns:

> Invalid extraction path '-1': array index -1 is off limits; must be between 0 and 2,147,483,647.

Interestingly, I can use `array_slice()` to get the *next-to-last* element:

```
select array_slice(a,-2,-1) from foo -- returns 'duck'
```

but not the last element, since "the output includes elements up to, but not including the element specfied [sic] by the parameter" ([doc](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_slice.html)).

How do I get the 'goose'?

Answer (score 11):

We could use the `a[len(a)-1]` approach:

```
with foo as (
  select array_construct('duck','duck','goose') as a
)
select a[array_size(a)-1]::varchar from foo -- returns 'goose'
```

Comment: Maybe this will help someone, but I'm hoping for a more readable solution.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here, `a[array_size(a)-1]` is pretty straightforward syntax? +1 for answering your own question though.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answer from C8H10N4O2 but without the CTE:

```
select  array_construct('duck','duck','goose') AS birds ,
birds[array_size(birds)-1]::STRING AS lastbird
```

Comment: For the win! This was the most concise and useful answer for me, just sayin'. Nice addition of CASTing as variable type too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a known maximum length of the array you can do this:

```
select array_slice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], -1, 9999)
```

where 9999 is bigger than the maximum length of the array

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ARRAY_ELEMENT(a ARRAY,b double)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS '
    if (B < 0) 
    {
        element = A[A.length + B];
    }
    else
    {
        element = A[B];
    }
    return element
';

select ARRAY_ELEMENT(array_construct(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),-1); //returns 6
select ARRAY_ELEMENT(array_construct(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),-2); //returns 5
```